# How can I modify the apache beam DirectRunner to make it faster?

Tags: apache-beam

We are building a framework using apache beam, and there are some use cases (like late data) that we simply don't need.  What we do need however, is blazing-fast performance.

I'm trying to modify the DirectRunner to be faster.  So far I've commented out Metrics and Enforcements, which yielded a small performance increase.  We've also removed SynchronizedProcessingTimeOutputWatermark and SynchronizedProcessingTimeInputWatermark without affecting our use case, which suggests that there may be more (Watermarks? Holds?) which could be removed.

I realise this is a rather vague question, but what else can I remove to make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running it with a profiler on your use cases? These would identify the hot spots that are affecting your performance.

You should know that the DirectRunner was written to demonstrate the model and validate the pipeline code. It wasn't written with performance or scalability as goals. If you're looking to run Beam pipelines efficiently, you may want to look at one of the distributed runners (such as Spark, Flink, Dataflow, etc.) since they will all perform better on large data.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  Although we are using SparkRunner for other use cases, this particular use case does not use big data - we are processing a single row of data at a time.  On the slack channel someone suggested the FlinkRunner, but that is hundreds of times slower for my pipeline.

Comment: I've done plenty of profiling and there is no egregious performer.  Seems most time is spent in various methods in the WatermarkManager (e.g. getMinHolds) which is why I'm trying to work out if I can remove either watermarks or holds.

Comment: Removing holds or watermarks will remove the ability for the runner to produce meaningful results. The WatermarkManager class almost certainly has areas where optimization would have large impacts on the performance of the pipeline with many items; timers and holds are likely the two places where most of this can be made.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using a "production" runner such as Flink in local mode.